# What should i put in the set and what should my condition be?

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop

Compute the income tax due on a taxable income entered by the user. Be sure to include error checking to make sure the user does not enter a negative number.  theres a chart as well

http://imgur.com/E5AqNxQ

What's making me stuck is what should be my condition,am i declaring the right thing and what should be the set?
i have 
declare incometax, taxdue, as float

call input

call set

call output

input

write " enter taxable income"

input taxable income

end input

set

i dont know.

output

help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are writing this in, but here's your solution in C. Bear in mind this is using Integers, not floats. So the answer will be truncated. Your problem from the textbook says to assume integer entries, hence why I have done this.

```
    int main()
{
    printf("Please enter your income: ");
    int iIncome = 0;
    int iTaxAmount = 0;
    char iChecking = 0;

    //use a while loop with our scanf to make sure a valid number is input.
    while (iChecking == 0)
    {
        scanf("%d", &iIncome);
        if (iIncome <= 0)
        {
            printf("Please enter a positive, nonzero number\n");
            printf("Please enter your income: ");
        }
        else
        {
            iChecking = 1;
        }
    }


    if (iIncome < 50000)
    {

        iTaxAmount = iIncome * 0.05;
    }
    else if (iIncome < 100000 && iIncome >= 50000)
    {
        //set base amount
        iTaxAmount = 2500;
        int iTaxableOver50k = 0;
        //calculate taxable amount over 50k
        iTaxableOver50k = iIncome - 50000;
        //add base tax to percent value
        iTaxAmount = iTaxAmount + iTaxableOver50k * 0.07;
    }
    else if (iIncome >= 100000)
    {
        //set base tax amount
        iTaxAmount = 6000;
        int iTaxableOver100k = 0;
        //calculate taxable amount over 100k
        iTaxableOver100k = iIncome - 100000;
        //add base tax to percent value
        iTaxAmount = iTaxAmount + iTaxableOver100k*0.09;
    }

    printf("\nYou must pay: $%d in tax\n", iTaxAmount);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's your solution using floating point calculations for the final answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Please enter your income: ");
    int iIncome = 0;
    float iTaxAmount = 0.0f;
    char iChecking = 0;

    //use a while loop with our scanf to make sure a valid number is input.
    while (iChecking == 0)
    {
        scanf("%d", &iIncome);
        if (iIncome <= 0)
        {
            printf("Please enter a positive, nonzero number\n");
            printf("Please enter your income: ");
        }
        else
        {
            iChecking = 1;
        }
    }


    if (iIncome < 50000)
    {

        iTaxAmount = (float)iIncome * 0.05f;
    }
    else if (iIncome < 100000 && iIncome >= 50000)
    {
        //set base amount
        iTaxAmount = 2500;
        int iTaxableOver50k = 0;
        //calculate taxable amount over 50k
        iTaxableOver50k = iIncome - 50000;
        //add base tax to percent value
        iTaxAmount = iTaxAmount + (float)iTaxableOver50k * 0.07f;
    }
    else if (iIncome >= 100000)
    {
        //set base tax amount
        iTaxAmount = 6000;
        int iTaxableOver100k = 0;
        //calculate taxable amount over 100k
        iTaxableOver100k = iIncome - 100000;
        //add base tax to percent value
        iTaxAmount = iTaxAmount + (float)iTaxableOver100k*0.09f;
    }


    printf("\nYou must pay: $%.2f in tax\n", iTaxAmount);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oops Its supposed to be psuedocode. But thanks, I actually kinda get what I'm supposed to do now thanks to that.

Comment: Cool glad it helped! Just one real quick thing though, the income amount should be multiplied by 0.0x instead of 1.0x because you're working out the % amount, not adding onto the original amount - i've just updated the post to reflect this :)